# Issues while taking Laravel project online

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, web-deployment, laravel-routing

I am trying to take my Laravel project online. I am using AWS to host it. The project is working fine in localhost. But when I try to put it online, I have to add `public` at the end of URL to view my project. Plus, no other route except `'/'` is working for me. For example, I have a route defined `user/login` which is working fine in localhost but not online. Here is the link  [to the project](http://goo.gl/50KjH7).

Comment: any htaccess? more likely cause

Comment: I am following [Laravel Installation Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/installation) for the htaccess configuration @nbin

Comment: try putting index.php after /public/
http://54.179.163.242/bag-tracker/public/index.php/user/login this works

Comment: You need to place your laravel files one folder back on your live server.  The `public` folder should be the root of your `public_html` folder on live.  I havn't used AWS so I'm not certain if they give you access to the parent folder or not.  Alernatively you will need to move the laravel folders into the `public` folder and change some of the path settings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correctly set the document root on your web server.  The document root is the folder that apache or nginx will attempt to serve files out of.  You want this to be the full path to the Laravel `public` folder.

I'm not an AWS expert, but if you're using Elastic Beanstalk checkout the "Document root" section on [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.container.html).  If you're just spinning up an EC2 instance you'll need to alter your deployment scripts to change the Apache virtual host setup and/or nginx configuration to point to the correct folder.

Answer (score -1):

Add a Procfile to your project root that contains something like the following:

web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public

The above assumes you are using php/apache, if it is something else, then change accordingly.